# How to return errors for client under coreography

Tags: microservices

Under orchestration it is pretty straightforward to return errors upstream (to the client).

```
Client <---> Orchestrator <---> Service A
                  "       <---> Service B
                  "       <---> Service C
```

The orchestrator can wait until all the responses from services A, B and C are received, before returning a success or error response to the client.

How can I do the same thing under coreography?

What I notice is that I would have something like this:

```
Client <---> Event Dispatcher --> "Order Submitted" Event

"Order Submitted" Event ---> Service A --> "Processing By Service A Succeeded" Event
"Order Submitted" Event ---> Service B --> "Processing By Service B Succeeded" Event
"Order Submitted" Event ---> Service C --> "Processing By Service C Succeeded" Event
```

I can subscribe the Client on the "Processing Succeeded" events. But that is not enough, because the client does not know how many answer events to expect. After the first response (say, from Service A succeded), it can be misguided to believe that the action was successfully processed, without knowledge that there are also Services B and C to react to the event. If the Client knew how many responses to expect, I feel that I'm coming back to the orchestrator pattern.

I mean, in the end of the day, someone has to be aware of all the collateral effects that are supposed to happen on the system (as a whole) after triggering an individual event, so to the consider the whole action as succeeded, partially succeeded, or failed.

Let's choose a concrete example to make the reasoning easier:

Suppose I have a client application that sends a SUBMIT ORDER command to the backend application:

With orchestrator, what I would do:

1. Client submits order to the orchestrator service
2. Send command (via messaging) to order service, which validates if order is valid
3. Send command (via messaging) to shipping service that checks if shipping is available for chosen address
4. Send command (via messaging) to inventory service to subtract quantity
5. Send command (via messaging) to payment service to charge credit card
6. Monitor that the 4 events were successfully processed
7. Send response to client

But with coregraphy, I would have:

1. Client dispatches event "ORDER PLACED" (could be done indirectly via a event dispatcher service)
2. Order service processes the event and check if it is valid
3. Shipping service processes the event and check if shipping is available
4. Inventory service processes the event and and subtract quantity
5. Payment service processes the event and charge credit card
6. ?
7. ?

I cannot see how steps 6 and 7 are plausible on this scheme, because the Client (or the indirect Event Dispatcher service) does now know how many services are going to react to the event that was just dispatched.

The steps 2, 3, 4 and 5 are totally hidden from the client. So how can I return errors for the client, showing that his action has succeeded/partially succeeded or failed?

Should I fall back to orchestrators, on this kind of problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Do your services send a response message to inform of the results of the processing?  Essentially, you would be waiting (most likely with a time-out) for the response message.

Comment: Yes, they are depicted as "Processing By Service A Succeeded", "Processing By Service B Succeeded" and "Processing By Service C Succeeded" in the coreography section. But the catch is that the Client does not know that services A, B and C react to the event "Order Submitted", because it is coreography.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch If your doubt was not very clear in my original question, and it is more clear now, I would be very thankful if you could improve my writing. Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps then I am having trouble picturing what you mean by the difference between orchestration and choreography.